# SUM two SQL rows with CodeIgniter in EE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, expressionengine

I'm working at summing two different rows and their field values (forum_total_topics and forum_total_posts) from a MySQL database in ExpressionEngine using the Active Record Class provided. I have tried multiple versions of code to sum the numbers. I have attempted and failed at passing a MySQL query to the request by saying.

```
$SQL = "SELECT forum_id, sum(forum_total_topics) + sum(forum_total_posts)
FROM exp_forums"

ee()->db->select($SQL); 
$query = ee->db->get('exp_forums');
echo $query;
```

to echo the total sum, and getting the following error:

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2
>
> SELECT (SELECT SUM(forum_total_topics) + SUM(forum_total_posts) FROM (`exp_forums`)

### A messy solution

So I've tried splitting the entire request up to find a solution.
I finally got the follow piece of code working by returning multiple arrays and summing those, but it looks quite messy. How, can I return and sum the two rows from the table in one line or so?

```
$topics = ee()->db->select_sum('forum_total_topics')->get('exp_forums');
foreach($topics->result_array() as $topicrow) {
    $totalTopics = $topicrow['forum_total_topics'];
}

$posts = ee()->db->select_sum('forum_total_posts')->get('exp_forums');
foreach($posts->result_array() as $postrow) {
    $totalPosts = $postrow['forum_total_posts'];
}

$total = $totalTopics + $totalPosts;
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

## Tried suggestions

I attempted suggestions like so,

```
$SQL = "SELECT forum_id, SUM(forum_total_topics + forum_total_posts) AS total
FROM exp_forums
GROUP BY forum_id";

$query = ee()->db->select($SQL); 
echo $query;
```

With this error instead.

> A PHP Error was encountered
> Severity: 4096
> Message: Object of class CI_DB_mysql_driver could not be converted to string
> Filename: libraries/Functions.php(679) : eval()'d code
> Line Number: 98

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this instead

```sql
SELECT forum_id, sum(forum_total_topics+forum_total_posts)
FROM exp_forums
GROUP BY forum_id
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9892e/2)</kbd>

Comment: Tried something like it earlier, but seems that EE/Active Record Class does not agree with it.. Edited my questions to show how I tried implementing this and your suggestions.

Comment: according to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264128/php-parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-variable-mysql-fetch-code), your problem might be a semilcolon after the query: "..GROUP BY forum_id"; <--

Comment: Oh sorry, missed that one, but still getting one of the errors from earlier: A PHP Error was encountered Message: Object of class CI_DB_mysql_driver could not be converted to string
Filename: libraries/Functions.php(679) : eval()'d code

Comment: That i don't know how to help you. I advise you to search for that error in stackoverflow, i'm sure you will find help. If not, open a new question, since this is no longer about the query, since this query will return what you want.

Comment: @FilipeSilva is correct.  The problem is that EE puts in the SELECT for you... see my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that you tried does not work due to a small syntax error I believe...

It should be:

```
$SQL = "forum_id, sum(forum_total_topics) + sum(forum_total_posts) FROM exp_forums"
```

The initial SELECT is being added in your class function so it should not appear in your $SQL:

```
 ee()->db->select($SQL);
```

That's why your error starts:

```
SELECT (SELECT
```

This is also the case with the code under "Tried Suggestions".

Comment: Good point, though it still won't function—I must be using the request methods from the Active Record Class incorrectly.. I may have found a lead from another post which I'll give a go.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT forum_id, SUM(forum_total_topics + forum_total_posts) AS total
FROM exp_forums
GROUP BY forum_id
```